# Outlook 2013 Instant Search fields greyed out

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

### Problem

We're using Outlook 2013 on a terminal server and we're unable to use the additional search fields (Instant Search (CTRL+E) --> click more --> select a field) as seen in the screenshot below. Even worse I can't even remove it, since the X is also disabled.
[image: Search fields greyed out]

### Steps I have tried:

- Office 2013 on a different terminal server: same issue.
- Run Outlook 2013 as administatror
- Checked version, is latest.

The search fields do however work on a workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that file indexing is disabled on the server machines, either by Group Policy or default.

- Make sure `Windows Search` and `Indexing Service` Windows features are installed
- If `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search\PreventIndexingOutlook` exists, change its value to 0
- Change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\SetupCompletedSuccessfully` to 0

---

If you have Server 2012 you will need to enable the 'Windows Search' feature via server manager.
(You can try going to programs and features and adding roles or features there which should open the server manager)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `Windows Search` is installed and running. `Indexing service` doesn't exist on server 2012. `PreventIndexingOutloo`k regkey doesn't exist and I've tried to reset the `SetupCompletedSuccesfully` but to no avail.

Comment: It seems Windows Search is not indexing Outlook (according to the indexing options). Thanks for your help pointing in the right direction. I'll post here if I managed to fix it.

Comment: In my case, I was running Outlook 2013 as Administrator. When I opened it as a normal user that "fixed" the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Server 2012 you will need to enable the 'Windows Search' feature via server manager. (You can try going to programs and features and adding roles or features there which should open the server manager)